# Casting string number to integer after __toString throws error

Tags: php, laravel, casting

I've got a weird problem, I made an equivalent of it which you can see below.
I **must** have the "__toString" method in the class and I **cannot** modify the way of reading it (via __toString) cause it's a framework's part.

```
class Integer{
    private $value = 2;
    
    **Must be implemented:**
    public function __toString(){
        return (string) $this->value;
    }
    
    public function asString(){
        return (string) $this->value;   
    }
}

$test = new Integer;

echo (int) $test->asString(); // 2
**Is used by framework:**
echo (int) $test; // Object of class Integer could not be converted to int
```

Is it possible to do something with it? Why it behaves like that?
Thanks in advance, I have no clue what to do.

## Update: Details

I'm using ValueObject as an ID parameter (how it looks now is presented in the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67550188/laravel-id-as-valueobject-is-null-after-save)). When I do "load" on a fetched row, the Query Builder runs this code (line 1020):

```
foreach ($values as &$value) {
    $value = (int) $value;
}
```

And then that error is throwed. I can't change this code. I think I should find a way to change my ValueObject, but I don't know how to do it in Laravel way.

Comment: You are relying on casting to int calling `__toString`, which doesn't happen. I don't understand what the issue is, which code you're allowed to modify and which you aren't. Have a look at this [related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751363/is-there-an-integer-equivalent-of-tostring), though.

Answer (score 1):

[`__toString`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) is only called when you try to represent an object as a string - here you are trying to represent it as an int. You need to cast it to a string first.

```
echo (int) (string) $test;
```

Comment: I updated my question, please look. When I change Laravel core code to yours, it works, but I can't do this.